# C#, Moq, Unit-Testing: How to create an object that inherits from another class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, moq

My classes/interfaces are set up like this:

**Room.cs**

```
//import statements

namespace namespace1
{
   internal class Room: Apartment
   {
      // constructor
      public Room(Furniture furniture) : base(furniture)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

**Apartment.cs**

```
// import statements

namespace namespace2
{
   public abstract class Apartment: Building
   {
      private int numChairs = 0;

      // constructor
      protected Apartment(IFurniture furniture) : base(IFurniture furniture)
      {
         this.numChairs = furniture.chairs.Length;
      }
   }
}
```

**Building.cs**

```
// import statements

namespace namespace3
{
   public abstract class Building
   {
      // constructor
      protected Building(IFurniture furniture)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

I want to create a Room object, with a mocked Furniture object. Here is what I have done:

```
[Test]
public void fun()
{
   var mockedFurniture = new Mock<IFurniture>();
   var room = new Room(mockedFurniture.Object);
}
```

The issue: because the constructor for `Room` calls `base(furniture)`, the constructor for `Apartment` is trying to access `furniture.chairs`, which is `null`. How can I mock this?

**EDIT**

The issue lies in `Apartment.cs`. It tries to access furniture.chairs, which is `null`. Here is IFurniture.cs:

```
public interface IFurniture
{
   IChairs Chairs { get; }
}
```

Comment: Mock what exactly? It looks like the test uncovered problem in the code and you simply need to fix the code itself... If you really want some help with code that you did not show  (like some mysterious `Furniture` class) you may want to [edit] the post to clarify that and show exactly what you want to mock and more importantly why do you think you must mock it. (I.e. DTO don't need to be mocked as those types amost never have any virtual members).

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code, which is way too complicated to put here. Furniture is not a simple object, but a very complex one that needs to be mocked. 

I guess, my question is: how do I create an object by passing in a mocked object into its constructor - if the constructors are going to try to access the mocked object's fields?

Comment: You really need to work on an [mre] for your exact problem... At very least show a proof that `new Room(new Furniture());` behaves differently from `new Room(new Mock<Furniture>().Object);` ... There is not much information to provide answer that is suitable for SO based on details currently present in the question.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question for some more context that I think will give more useful information.

Comment: I am also confused, is this only chairs field causing the problem or there are a lot of properties that have the same problem? if it is only this field manually fill it or use AutoFixture or AutoBugos libraries ... `mockedFurniture.Object.chairs = "1234";`,
with the given information this is all we can do for you. :)

Comment: @AliRezaSabouri I've provided a small update, please see if that helps? The issue is that the only field in IFurniture is read only. So, it cannot directly be mocked with ```....Object.chairs```.

Comment: As a side note, a `Room` is not a type of a `Building`. Consider composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your example, you need to mock `IChairs` too.

```cs
var mockedChairs = new Mock<IChairs>();
var mockedFurniture = new Mock<IFurniture>();
mockedFurniture.Setup(q=>q.Chairs).Returns(mockedChairs.Object);
var room = new Room(mockedFurniture.Object);
```

Comment: Good answer -- and posted a minute faster than my version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up your mock.

```
[Test]
public void fun()
{
   var expectedChair = new Chair() {
       HasCushion = true  //etc
   };
   var mockedFurniture = new Mock<IFurniture>();
   mockedFurniture.Setup(furniture => furniture.Chairs).Returns(expectedChair);
   var room = new Room(mockedFurniture.Object);
}
```

Note that `expectedChair` could easily be a `mockChair` instead.